# How to convert Func<T, TResult> to Func<T>

Tags: c#, delegates, action, func

I have `Func<object, bool> myDelegate` and 
some variable like this:

```
object test = new object();
```

How can I pass `myDelegate` through to a method expecting a `Func<bool>` argument:

```
class FuncT
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object test = new object();
        Func<object, bool> myDelegate = (x) => x != null;

        // how to pass myDelegate to methodName so that it evaluates against 'test'?
        methodName(myDelegate);
    }

    static void methodName(Func<bool> criteria)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Criteria: {0}", criteria());
    }
}
```

As alternative, I can change the method to have signature like `void methodName(object a, Func<object, bool> criteria)` and call it `methodName (test, myDelegate)`, but why? I already have `test` variable of object type, so I would like to tell `myDelegate` to use it inside the method, so that methodName would get only a delegate without parameters.

Comment: do you want to apply the **instance** `test`, or the method that **creates** `test`? Only the latter can be applied to a delegate of course.

Comment: you may pass `() => myDelegate(test);` ... but seriosuly, question is unclear

Comment: Next time be a little less abstract with your variable and method names, you're not losing any IP here. Just try to create a real-world or at least relatable  problem statement. This is a common requirement, especially with Linq and lambda expressions, once you understand it you'll never look back.

Comment: I've edited your question, as @Selvin has pointed out, its as simple as this: `methodName(() => myDelegate(test));`